# Jquery replaceWith(html) not replacing element; appending it to end instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML.  Its a form inside of a modal window:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="requestModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="requestModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog wide-modal" role="document">
        <form novalidate>
            <div class="modal-content">
            ....
            </div>
       </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever the form is opened, I want to render a fresh version of the form, free of any old inputs or error messages.  The following handler gets the data for hidden fields plus the form's HTML I can obtain the data for the form along with the raw HTML for the form via an Ajax request:

```
$(document).on('click', '#por-detail-tbl .dropdown-menu', e => {

    // This route will get fresh form HTML also.
    $.get(`/projects/${$(e.target).attr('project-id')}`, res => {
        $('#requestModal').replaceWith(res.html)

        ...more code here to populate hidden fields...
    })
})
```

I would expect the `$('#requestModal')` element to be replaced with whatever `res.html` is (in this case, a new version of the form).  Instead, `res.html` is getting inserted as the last element in the document body.  The old `$('#requestModal')` is still there.

Here is a snippet from `res.html`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="requestModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="requestModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog wide-modal" role="document">
        <form novalidate>
            <div class="modal-content">
            ...
            </div>
        </form>
     <div>
</div>
```

I'm able to use this technique successfully in other Ajax callbacks.  Any ideas why this one is behaving strangely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want jQuery's `.html()` function here.

In your original code, the `replaceWith()` function *replaces* `$('#requestModal')`. But the element you replaced is the element that's been manipulated by Bootstrap to perform the modal behavior you expect.

So I think you really want to set the content of the `div.modal-dialog` element to just the `form` and its children. If you can pare down `res.html` to just the form and children, you can change `$('#requestModal').replaceWith(res.html)` to `$('#requestModal').find('div.modal-dialog').html(res.html)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had thought of something similar, but like I said I use `replaceWith` to "zero-out" the form in several other places in the app & didn't want to have to change them all.  Oh well.  Thanks again!